# Pointwise and uniformly convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{(x + 1)^n}{1 + (x - 1)^n}$ in $R\backslash\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis

To study the pointwise convergence have I to study the different cases in which $(x-1)^n$ and $(x+1)^n$ are convergent or divergent?

1) $x>2$ $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}(1+\frac{2}{x+1})^n=+\infty$

2) $x=2 \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} {{(3)^n}\over{2}}=+\infty $

3) $x\in (0,2) \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}(x+1)^n=+\infty$

but for $x<0$?

Comment: Maybe have a closer look at case 4? The numerator and denominator have no limit, but that doesn't imply that their quotient has no limit.

Comment: Try dividing both the numerator and the denominator by $(x+1)^n $

Comment: if I divide what I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x<0.$ Verify that then

$$\tag 1  |x+1|<|x-1|.$$

Now

$$\tag 2f_n(x) = \frac{[(x+1)/(x-1)]^n}{[1/(x-1)]^n + 1}.$$

$(1)$ shows the numerator has the form $a^n,$ where $|a|<1.$ Hence the numerator $\to 0.$ The denominator has the form $b^n+1,$ where $|b|<1.$ Hence the denominator $\to 1.$ This implies the limit  of $(2)$ is $0/1 =0.$

Comment: there is pointwise convergence in $(-\infty,0)$ but not uniform?